# Linq groupby orderby and join together

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I have two tables Appointments and Patients,  consider they have the data in the following manner: Please find the db schema in the

[image: attached image]

The above are my tables with data. My scenario is I have to get the patients with respect to a particular doctor . The below query works but does not give distinct results . I get same patient data more than once, I can use distinct after retrieval of results, but I have to perform the operation in the line query itself (In the db itself)

```
from a in dbContext.Appointments
where a.doctorid == mydoctorid 
join p in dbContext.Patients on a.patientid equals p.patientid
order by p.name

updated code which led to exception

(from p in this.dbContext.Patients
join b in ( from a in this.dbContext.Appointments
            join p in this.dbcontext.Patient on a.Patientid equals p.id
            where a.doctorid == doctorid
            group a by a.Patientid into pg)
            on p.Patientid equals b.FirstOrDefault().Patientid
            order by p.Name
            select new { p.Patientid, p.Name }).ToList()

final code which i tried:

            (from p in this.m_dbContext.Patient
            join b in (from a in this.m_dbContext.Appointments
            join p in this.m_dbContext.Patient on a.Patientid equals 
            p.Patientid
            where a.Doctorid == doctorid && a.Clinicid == clinicid
            group a by a.Patientid)
            on p.Patientid equals b.FirstOrDefault().Patientid
            orderby p.Name
            select new
            {
              p.Patientid,
              p.Clinicid,
              p.Name,
              p.Mobilenumber,
              p.Gender,
              p.Dob,
              p.Age,
              p.Address,
              p.City,
              p.State,
              p.Pincode
           }).ToList().Count();
```

Exception:

The LINQ expression 'FirstOrDefault(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: a.patientid, 
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: Appointments
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Did you try putting a `.Distinct()` on the query?

Comment: distinct is working but it is client side, I have to perform in the db itself...

Comment: for each appointment booked, an entry will be added, I by mistake added the same time , actually for different time, appointments will be booked and entry will be added

Comment: select will be p.name alone , distinct is like fetching from the db (for example I will be getting all the records including the duplicated records), then only distinct can be applied, I need to filter in the linqq itself, group by would be an option, but I am unable to get the correct syntax

Comment: @HariKrishnanVasanthamaniRag - What makes you think that `.Distinct()` is client-side?

Comment: Most entity framework providers (if not all) will be able to include `Distinct` as part of the SQL query so it will run server-side, not client-side. It's not because there is no query syntax equivalent for `Distinct` that it's treated differently.

Comment: query is executed in the db, so I will get 10 rows for example, in these 10 rows, 8 may be duplicate data and 2 may be unique, so the result is only 3 rows, but the data retrieved from the db would be 10 rows, then after retrieval only distinct can be applied. CLIENT SIDE means consider the api as client and the db as server

Comment: @HariKrishnanVasanthamaniRag - Yes, but why do you think that `.Distinct()` is client-side?

Comment: so ok lets not consider it as client side.. but I need only unique rows from the db... is there any other solution.. Distinct is executed only after fetching the all the duplicate and unique rows from the database and then if we apply distinct, it will give us the result. But I have to perform it in the db itself

Comment: Why is said as client because, I got an exception earlier while using group by, the exception was CLIENT SIDE GROUP BY IS NOT ALLOWED. So I came to know that .net considers db as server and the api instance as client..

Comment: @HariKrishnanVasanthamaniRag - `.Distinct()` is run on the database.

Comment: ((from a in dbContext.Appointments
where a.doctorid == mydoctorid 
join p in dbContext.Patients on a.patientid equals p.patientid
order by p.name
select new { p.patientid, p.name }).Distinct().ToList()        @vc74

Comment: let me check it out once again and il come back @Enigmativity

Answer (score 1):

Schema naming convention is slightly different but you can get your desired output through the following query.

This query fetches all the unique patients using group by then get name through sub query.

Consider changing p.Id with p.PatientId

```
from p in dbContext.Patients
join b in (from a in dbContext.Appointments
      join p in dbContext.Patients on a.PatientId equals p.Id
      where a.DoctorId == mydoctorId
      group a by a.PatientId)
on p.Id equals b.FirstOrDefault().PatientId
select new {p.Id, p.Name}
```

Comment: will check it and let you know, sorry just now checking @Muhammad

Comment: I think you'll find it redundant to do `into pg select pg` - you should be able to leave those off.

Comment: But ```select new {p.Id, p.Name}``` can be replaced by ```select  p ```

Comment: @Enigmativity yes you are right. I have also updated my answer

Comment: it throws query translation exception @Muhammad, the exception says FirstOrDefault() could not be translated

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right, Distinct() doesn't happen in the client side...

Comment: @Muhammad I have updated the code, which led to the exception in the question I posted

Comment: Kindly change p.id to p.patientid according to your schema and also change other keys according to your schema. Also change Patientid  to patientid as sql is case sensitive when defining variables

Comment: I have used the variables as in my Models class, the problem is with FirstOrDefault() which says it could not be translated.. @Muhammad... I Have used order by also, should that be a reason for the exception, please check my updated code in the post

Comment: No orderby is not the cause for exception. But its working fine on my end

Comment: @Muhammad , i have updated the code again, it compiles good, i have just shared the db schema with reduced columns than mine for easy understanding of the problem... My code compiles good .. il also post the exception below the updated code

Comment: Try changing this line  ```p.Id equals b.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().PatientId```

Comment: Processing of the LINQ expression 'AsQueryable<Appointments>(AsEnumerable<Appointments>(NavigationTreeExpression
    Value: default(IGrouping<long, Appointments>)
    Expression: (Unhandled parameter: e)))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

Comment: If i change to asenumerable(), i get the above exception, i know im troubling you a lot @Muhammad... but im stuck with this the whole day without knowing the syntax

Comment: thanks very much the issue is solved.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61502453/13433178

Comment: @Hari If you find my answer useful. Fell free to vote it out

Comment: I don't have reputations to vote , it shows like that what should I do?  @Muhammad